# How do you take a picture with camerax?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

I'm still practicing with Kotlin and Android Developing. As far as I understood, Camera class has been deprecated, and Android invites to use Camerax instead, because this high-level class is device-indipendent, and they've made simpler the process of implementing cameras on apps.

I've tried to read the documentation (https://developer.android.com/training/camerax) but it's written so bad I barely understood what they are trying to explain.
So I went to read the entire sample code given in the documentation itself (https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/CameraXBasic).
The CameraFragment code is about 500 lines long (ignoring imports and various comments).

Do I really need to write 500 lines of code to simply take a picture?
How is this supposed to be considered "simpler than before"?

I mean, Android programming is at the point where I just need to write only 4 lines of code to ask the user to select an Image from his storage and retreive it and show it in an ImageView.
Is there a TRUE simple way to take a picture, or do I really need to stop and lose a whole day of work to write all those lines of code?

EDIT:
Take this page of the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/architecture#kotlin
It starts with this piece of code.

```
val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
val viewFinder: PreviewView = findViewById(R.id.previewView)

// The use case is bound to an Android Lifecycle with the following code
val camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview)
```

cameraProvider comes out of nowhere. What is this supposed to be? I've found out it's a ProcessCameraProvider, but how am I supposed to initialize it?
Should it be a lateinit var or has it already been initialized somewhere else?
Because if I try to write `val cameraProvider = ProcessCameraProvider()` I get an error, so what am I supposed to do?
What is cameraSelector parameter? It's not defined before. I've found out it's the selector for the front or back camera, but how am I supposed to know it reading that page of the documentation?
How could have this documentation been released with these kind of lackings?
How is someone supposed to learn with ease?

Comment: if you need to take picture you could use a external camera app that does it for you gives your app the result. https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

Comment: Wasn't this deprecated?

Comment: I can't use anything that's been deprecated, even if it's working, as I'm practicing to be able to work on a long term project, and so I'll need to avoid deprecated functions. Aren't somewhere some good written examples about camerax?

Comment: i thinks its best to follow the sample from google itself. if you have any queries you can always ask a question here. We are not using camera api in the link i posted. We are using external camera app to which takes photos and gives result back. I am not sure why the page says deprecated. I think camera api 1 is deprecated.

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#1

Comment: I had already seen that link, the code is full of errors even if I copy-paste it

Comment: The deprecation notice on the top of https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics was only meant to be added to the 'Controlling the Camera' section, not the bit about using Intents asking for an image from the device's default camera app.  So the content in the 'Take photos' section is still valid.

Comment: "This page uses the Camera class, which has been deprecated", they should be clearer then... Anyway thank you both, after @Husayn Hakeem's answer I think I'll stick with camerax, since it will give more possibilities on future developments for the project I'm working on.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Before you can interact with the device's cameras using CameraX, you need to initialize the library. The initialization process is asynchronous, and involves things like loading information about the device's cameras.

You interact with the device's cameras using a `ProcessCameraProvider`. It's a Singleton, so the first time you get an instance of if, CameraX performs its initialization.

```
val cameraProviderFuture: ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context)
```

Getting the `ProcessCameraProvider` singleton returns a `Future` because it might need to initialize the library asynchronously. The first time you get it, it might take some time (usually well under a second), subsequent calls though will return immediately, as the initialization will have already been performed.

With a `ProcessCameraProvider` in hand, you can start interacting with the device's cameras. You choose which camera to interact with using a `CameraSelector`, which wraps a set of filters for the camera you want to use. Typically, if you're just trying to use the main back or front camera, you'd use `CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA` or `CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA`.

Now that you've defined which camera you'll use, you build the use cases you'll need. For example, you want to take a picture, so you'll use the `ImageCapture` use case. It allows taking a single capture frame (typically a high quality one) using the camera, and providing it either as a raw buffer, or storing it in a file. To use it, you can configure it if you'd wish, or you can just let CameraX use a default configuration.

```
val imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder().build()
```

In CameraX, a camera's lifecycle is controlled by a `LifecycleOwner`, meaning that when the `LifecycleOwner`'s lifecycle starts, the camera opens, and when it stops, the camera closes. So you'll need to choose a lifecycle that will control the camera. If you're using an `Activity`, you'd typically want the camera to start as the `Activity` starts, and stop when it stops, so you'd use the `Activity` instance itself as the `LifecycleOwner`, if you were using a `Fragment`, you might want to use its view lifecycle (`Fragment.getViewLifecycleOwner()`).

Lastly, you need to put the pieces of the puzzle together.

```
processCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
   lifecycleOwner,
   cameraSelector,
   imageCapture
)
```

An app typically includes a viewfinder that displays the camera's preview, so you can use a `Preview` use case, and bind it with the `ImageCapture` use case. The `Preview` use case allows streaming camera frames to a `Surface`. Since setting up the `Surface` and correctly drawing the preview on it can be complex, CameraX provides `PreviewView`, a `View` that can be used with the `Preview` use case to display the camera preview. You can check out how to use them [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/preview#select-camera-bind).

```
// Just like ImageCapture, you can configure the Preview use case if you'd wish.
val preview = Preview.Builder().build()

// Provide PreviewView's Surface to CameraX. The preview will be drawn on it.
val previewView: PreviewView = findViewById(...)
preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)

// Bind both the Preview and ImageCapture use cases
processCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
   lifecycleOwner,
   cameraSelector,
   imageCapture,
   preview
)
```

Now to actually take a picture, you use on of `ImageCapture`'s `takePicture` methods. One provides a JPEG raw buffer of the captured image, the other saves it in a file that you provide (make sure you have the necessary storage permissions if you need any).

```
imageCapture.takePicture(
   ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context), // Defines where the callbacks are run
   object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
      override fun onCaptureSuccess(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
         val image: Image = imageProxy.image // Do what you want with the image
         imageProxy.close() // Make sure to close the image
      }

      override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
         // Handle exception
      }
   }
)
```

```
val imageFile = File("somePath/someName.jpg") // You can store the image in the cache for example using `cacheDir.absolutePath` as a path.
val outputFileOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions
      .Builder(imageFile)
      .build()
takePicture(
   outputFileOptions,
   CameraXExecutors.mainThreadExecutor(),
   object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
      override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                }

      override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
      }
   }
)
```

> Do I really need to write 500 lines of code to simply take a picture?
> How is this supposed to be considered "simpler than before"?

CameraXBasic is not as "basic" as its name might suggest x) It's more of a complete example of CameraX's 3 use cases. Even though the `CameraFragment` is long, it explains things nicely so that it's more accessible to everyone.

CameraX is "simpler than before", before referring mainly to Camera2, which was a bit more challenging to get started with at least. CameraX provides a more developer-friendly API with its approach to using use cases. It also handles compatibility, which was a big issue before. Ensuring your camera app works reliably on most of the Android devices out there is very challenging.

Comment: Would like to add that Camera2 is useless because it is unsupported on some devices. AFAIK CameraX tries to process such incompatibilities by fallback to Camera1. The API is crap anyway.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev That's actually not the case, CameraX is built entirely on Camera2, it doesn't have a Camera1 implementation. AFAIK, all Android devices (this includes not just phones, but tablets, some POS devices, etc) that support Android Lollipop (API level 21) support Camera2.

Comment: This should be on the official documentation!
Clearest as anyone could have ever been.